# Find all holomorphic functions $f:D\to\mathbb C$ where $D$ is the open unit disc such that $f(\frac{1}{n^3})=\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all holomorphic functions $f:D\to\mathbb C$ where $D$ is the open unit disc such that $f(\frac{1}{n^3})=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\{2,3,4,..,\}$. I've just done a similar question for $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n^3}$ where I've shown $f(z)=z^3$ necessarily by the identity theorem. I think that there are no such functions, $f(z)=z^{\frac{1}{3}}$ works but isn’t holomorphic. If there aren’t any, how would I show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(0)=0$ by continuity, so if $g(z)=f(z^3)$ holomorphic on the open disc, one has $g(z)-z=0, z=0,1/2,..1/n,..$ so by the identity principle $g(z)=z$ or $f(z^3)=z$

Writing the Taylor series of $f(z)=a_1z+a_2z^2+..$ we get $z=a_1z^3++..$ for all $|z|<1$ and that is obviously impossible so we are done and no such $f$ exists

Comment: Do we need to use that $f(0)=0$? Can’t we use the identity principle knowing that $g(z)-z=0$ for $z=1/2,1/3,...$? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: happy to be of help - it is true that it is enough to know $g(z)-z=0, z=1/2,..$ but that implies $g(0)=0$ so $f(0)=0$ anyway

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(\frac{1}{n^3}) = \frac{1}{n}$, one gets that $f(0) = 0$ based on definition of derivate f(z) is not differentiable at $0$.